# Is it possible to use map function and filter function in if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array object data called place. When the place array enters the solution function, if the object in the place has a TYPE called 'BOX', I want to extract only the placeId array with 'BOX' TYPE by subtracting the TYPE data of "CONTAINER". Also, if there is no 'BOX' TPYE and only CONTAINER TYPE, I want to extract only the placeId array with "CONAINER" TPYE.

I tried using the map function and filter function in the if statement, but it failed to extract the data and my code doesn't look good either. How do I fix the code?

```
const place = [
  {type: "CONTAINER", placeId: 252 }
]

const place = [
  {type: "CONTAINER", placeId: 252 }, {type: "BOX", placeId: 257}, {type: "BOX", placeId: 258}
]


  function solution(place) {


  if(plaecs.map((v) => v.type === 'BOX')) {
        return plaecs.filter((v) => v.type !== 'CONTAINER')
    } else if (plaecs.map((v) => v.type !== 'BOX')) {
        return plaecs.filter((v) => v.type === "CONTAINER")
    }


  }

solution(place)
</script>
</body>
</html>



solution(place)    expected answer : [252]

solution(place)    expected answer : [ 257, 258]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map` method returns an array. Using `if (someArray)` will always go into the body of the `if`, because all arrays are truthy (even empty ones).

You're probably looking for the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
if (plaecs.some((v) => v.type === 'BOX')) {
```

The `some` method determines if any element in the array matches the predicate defined by the callback:¹ it calls its callback with the first element of the array and, if the callback returns a truthy value, stops and returns `true`; otherwise, it calls the callback with the second element of the array and applies the same logic; etc. If no call to the callback returns a truthy value, `some` returns `false` (including on an empty array).

---

¹ So why is it called `some` rather than `any`? Because it was added in 2009, and some libraries were already adding an `any` method to arrays with slightly different semantics, and analysis of existing code in the wild showed that adding `any` would break that code. So they went with the second-best name: `some`.